# External Jars in to spring boot application deployed in heroku

Tags: java, spring, maven, heroku, spring-boot

This question may seems duplicate but I tried all the options but no luck.

I want to add a external jar which is not there in maven repository in to my spring boot bulk jar. This application is deployed in the heroku cloud and is ran using the command

```
java -Dserver.port=$PORT  -jar target/myjar.jar
```

I tried various scenarios to fix this

**1.**

```
<dependency>
         <groupId>exjar</groupId>
         <artifactId>exjar</artifactId>
         <scope>system</scope>
         <version>JDK7</version>
         <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/exjar-JDK7.jar</systemPath>
      </dependency>
```

**2.**

```
java -Dserver.port=$PORT -Dloader.path="lib/*" -jar target/myjar.jar
```

**3.**
maven-install-plugin

None of the above worked. I want to try below approach, any idea of how to execute this command in heroku?

```
mvn install:install-file
   -Dfile=<path-to-file>
   -DgroupId=<group-id>
   -DartifactId=<artifact-id>
   -Dversion=<version>
   -Dpackaging=<packaging>
   -DgeneratePom=true
```

Any solution is appreciated.

Comment: For 2, change your `layout` configuration of spring-boot-maven-plugin to [`ZIP`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/usage.html#Repackaging_an_application), so that `loader.path` will be picked by `PropertiesLauncer`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add following repository in you pom

```
<repositories>  
   <repository>
     <id>external</id>
     <name>External Project Repo</name>
     <url>file:///${project.basedir}/lib</url>
   </repository>
</repositories>
```

then add the dependency

```
  <dependency>
     <groupId>exjar</groupId>
     <artifactId>exjar</artifactId>
     <version>jdk7</version>
  </dependency>
```

When you finished building your myjar.jar should have `BOOT-INF/lib/exjar-jdk7.jar`